# Flutter expand Row and align children with spaceBetween inside of horizontal SingleChildScrollView

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm creating a SliverList with a list of Rows as children. These Rows create the layout which is seen in the image below.
I have wrapped the Column which contains the text and the delete icon on the right side with a `SingleChildScrollView` to counter the overflow on smaller devices.
But I would now like to position the delete icon and issued text away from each other, through `mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,` on the parent Row. But because I use the SingleChildScrollView this is no longer possible because the horizontal space is now infinte.

Is there a way to still align the children of the row with `spaceBetween` or a `Spacer()` to push them away from each other while countering the overflow with a SingleChildScrollView?

```
SliverList(
  delegate: SliverChildListDelegate(
    [
      for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++)
        Row(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
          children: [
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10.0, left: 20.0),
              child: Text(
                children[i].issuanceDate),
              ),
            ),
            Column(
              //vertical line
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              width: 10,
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0),
                child: Container(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                      vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 20.0),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6),
                    color: Colors.white,
                    boxShadow: [
                      BoxShadow(
                        color: (Colors.grey[200])!,
                        offset: const Offset(0, 8),
                        blurRadius: 8,
                        spreadRadius: 1.0,
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                  child: SingleChildScrollView(
                    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                    child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        Row(
                          children: [
                            Text(
                              children[i]
                                  .credentialSubject
                                  .documentName,
                              style:
                                  Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText1,
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                        Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment:
                              MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                          children: [
                            Text(
                              "${L.of(context).issued}${children[i].issuanceDate}",
                              overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                            ),
                            IconButton(
                              icon: Icon(
                                Icons.delete,
                                color: Theme.of(context).errorColor,
                              ),
                              onPressed: () => print("delete $i"),
                            ),
                          ],
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              width: 20,
            ),
          ],
        )
    ],
  ),
),
```

[image]

**Edit:**
I now changed the Row to `Wrap` but it still doesn't expand to the full width of the Column, as seen in the image above

I changed the Row to a Wrap in the code snippet below and removed the SingleChildScrollView but I still can't wrap my `Wrap` with the Expanded Widget because the incoming height constraints are unbounded.

```
Wrap(
  alignment: WrapAlignment.center,
  crossAxisAlignment: WrapCrossAlignment.center,
  children: [
    Text(
      "${L.of(context).issued}${DateFormat.yMMMd().format(DateTime.parse(children[i].issuanceDate).toLocal())}",
      style: Theme.of(context)
          .textTheme
          .bodyText2!
          .copyWith(
              color: Theme.of(context)
                  .colorScheme
                  .onBackground
                  .withOpacity(0.5)),
      overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
      softWrap: true,
    ),
    IconButton(
      icon: Icon(
        Icons.delete,
        color: Theme.of(context).errorColor,
      ),
      onPressed: () => print("delete $i"),
    ),
  ],
)
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to use singlechildscrollview(SCSW) to counter the overflow. It seems like a bad Ux for users to scroll the tile. You can let flow vertically using something like softwrap.
If you still want to use SCSW then you can try to put constraints on SCSW by wrapping the child of SCSW in ConstrainedBox.

```
constraints: BoxConstraints(maxWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width),
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I now used a Wrap instead of a Row to align the issued text and the delete icon but the wrap still doesn't expand to the available vertical space. I edited my question to give some more details on my change.